# Sitecore Analytics: Data is not coming on Assets->Download

Tags: experience-analytics

I am using Sitecore 10.1.2, and I want to track downloaded assets. To achieve this I followed the below steps:

1. Created Assets here `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Taxonomies/Asset` and deployed it.
2. In the media library, selected `Marketing assets` which I created into point 1.
3. On the media item, in the attribute, I selected `Download` event.
4. Deployed media item and published.
5. Deployed marketing definitions from the Control panel.
6. From `Indexing Manager`, indexed `sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master` and `sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web`

but after all these steps, I am not getting download assets in Experience Analytics.

I followed this document https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/classify-a-media-item-as-a-digital-marketing-asset.html and https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/deploy-marketing-definitions-and-taxonomies.html

Answer (score 0):

As checked, you are correct in the configuration on Sitecore Track downloading.
While please verify if you have set up the following correctly.

1. Verify the media item is under the taxonomy folder, like `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Taxonomies/Asset`.
2. Ensure all the assets are published and deployed successfully to the public
3. Check the indexing status (**sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master** and **sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web**) and if it's out of date.
4. Review the Sitecore logs for any errors or exception when tracking is triggered.

Hope it helps !